# youtube analytics api error 403, accessNotConfigured

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to execute the java sample code for pulling YouTubeAnalyticsReports.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/java

I get com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Access Not Configured",
    "reason" : "accessNotConfigured"
  } ],

I have configured the access for Services-YouTube Analytics API.

When the ran for the first time, a browser came up and I had to give permission for the application to access the data. I have been getting the 403 error after that. I have checked the quota and I have hardly used any.

Answer (score 1):

My fault, I did not have the access turned on for the DataAPI. I was under the impression that I needed only the AnalyticsAPI

Answer (score 1):

You haven't enabled YouTube Analytics API v3 and Data API v3 in your [devconsole](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). Once you enable and wait for 15 minutes, it should work.